# Call back method between

Tags: java, android, callback

I'm new to android and I need little help please. I want to pass data from an activity to a `framelayout` class, so I've implement a callback. On my activity I use an interface and setting the listener like this:

```
private OnCallStateListener onCallStateListener;

public interface OnCallStateListener{
            int Data = 1;


           void OnCallState(int wichAction)
    }

public void setOnCallStateListener(OnCallStateListener listener){
    onCallStateListener = listener;

}

private void dispatchTriggerEvent(int whichHandle){
    if(onCallStateListener != null){
        onCallStateListener.OnCallState(whichHandle);
    }
}
```

And I use it like:

```
    private onCallDisconnect(){
    dispatchTriggerEvent(OnCallStateListener.DATA);
```

The `dispatchTriggerEvent` is executed but the problem is that the listener `onCallStateListener` is always null. what am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is null because you did not create an instance of the class.  From what you have here you only have an interface.  You would first need to create a class that implements that interface, and then say something like:

```
 OnCallStateListener myVar = new OnCallStateListenerImpl();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. the interface has been created inside the activity. i have already implement the interface on the framelayout class, where i get the listener to call.

  activity.setOnCallStateListener(this);
I did the opposite, create the interface on framelayout class, implement the interface on activity and get the listener and it works! From activity does not work. its null. 
thanks again

Comment: @user2699406 if my answer helped you please press the green check mark.  Thanks.